# Java program not terminating when using scanner with System.in

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, eof

I am unable to terminate my java program which takes some strings as input, below is the code I used to  process the input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EPALIN {

public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String p = null;
    while((p=sc.nextLine())!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(getPalin(p));
    }
    sc.close(); 
}

public static String getPalin(String st)
{
    int i =0;
    int j = st.length()-1;

    String res = "";

    while(i<=j)
    {
        if(st.substring(i, i+1).equals(st.substring(j, j+1)))
        {
            res+=st.substring(i, i+1);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else
        {
            res+=st.substring(i,i+1);
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(res.length()%2==0)
    return res+(new StringBuffer(res).reverse().toString());
    else
        return res+(new StringBuffer(res).reverse().toString().substring(1));   
}
}
```

Even using

```
while((p=sc.nextLine())!="")
```

didn't work, its a problem from SPOJ problemId EPALIN

Comment: What is `sc` in your code?

Comment: Yes show us full code

Comment: sc is probably java.util.Scanner, but what is getPalin?

Comment: If this *is* Scanner, as far as I can tell, `nextLine()` never returns `null`. It would be appropriate for BufferedReader though. You haven't really told us enough about what's going on for us to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet used BufferedReader too, still same issue.

Comment: You haven't told us what you're doing to try to end the program... And no, comparing strings using == or != isn't going to work...

Comment: "using while((p=sc.nextLine())!="") didn't work" yes you can't compare a string with != or == , you need to use equals method

Comment: @JonSkeet typically the "judge" pipes a file to stdin, so main() is written as a loop which reads each line and prints responses until hitting EOF. Like you said, OP should be using BufferedReader, or at least using Scanner properly.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this

```
while(!(p=sc.nextLine()).equals("")) {
// ...
}
```

I try your code with the while i'm using and it's seems to work.

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String p = null;
    while(!(p=sc.nextLine()).equals(""))
    {
        System.out.println(getPalin(p));
    }
    sc.close(); 
}

public static String getPalin(String st)
{
    int i=0;
    int j=st.length()-1;

    String res = "";

    while(i<=j)
    {
        if(st.substring(i, i+1).equals(st.substring(j, j+1)))
        {
            res+=st.substring(i, i+1);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else
        {
            res+=st.substring(i,i+1);
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(res.length()%2==0)
        return res+(new StringBuffer(res).reverse().toString());
    else
        return res+(new StringBuffer(res).reverse().toString().substring(1));   
}
```

}

Comment: Tried this and it terminates more cleanly than mine.

Comment: Worked. Thanks, my bad forgot that, equals should be used for comparing strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should use hasNext()

```
String delimiter = "\r\n|\r"; //Or try System.getProperty("line.separator");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
scanner.useDelimiter(delimiter);  

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        String p = scanner.next();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the Scanner [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29). `Scanner.nextLine()` won't return null. If the input ends (for instance, the judge has piped a file to stdin, and the file ends), it will instead throw `NoSuchElementException`. If it doesn't, `nextLine()` will block.

Ordinarily what you could do here, because the the [problem description](http://www.spoj.com/problems/EPALIN/) states that each test case will be on its own line is (similar to what CandiedOrange suggested):

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    ...
}
```

However, the problem also states:

> *Large I/O. Be careful in certain languages.*

In contest problem lingo, this means "don't use Scanner." For fast I/O, you have a couple of options, but something like the following should work fine while keeping you under the time limit:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {    
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in));

    String line;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
        doSomething(line); // etc
}
```

Note that you will most likely also have to collect all of your output and print it at the end, rather than making a bunch of `System.out.println()`, which have overhead that you can avoid by only printing once.

Comment: Your BufferedReader code doesn't terminate for me.  Even when I type alt 0.  Try this: while ((line = in.readLine()).length() != 0)

Comment: Hm. It's exactly the template I use for UVa OnlineJudge problems. Are you invoking it like e.g. "java ClassName < input.txt"? (Mind you I could be wrong in assuming that SPOJ's site works exactly like UVa's).

Comment: Nevermind, you said you were doing it interactively. I'm not sure how you'd mimic the EOF behavior then... does typing Alt-0 produce ^D? Is that a Windows thing? Just curious.

Comment: I was trying it in eclipse under windows.  ctrl-d doesn't terminate it either.  Sure you aren't making your OS stop it?

Comment: From what I can tell, ^D just doesn't work right in Eclipse, even though there's a binding for it. But the pattern above will behave correctly when called from a terminal (whether typing ^D or piping a file). Checking if the line length is zero will cause the program to quit on blank lines or crash if the file ends before any are encountered.